# Show that $f$ is still integrable after altering it at one point

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-writing, alternative-proof

> Let $f$ be an integrable function on $[a, b]$.
>
> Show that $f$ remains integrable on $[a,b]$ if we alter it at one single point and that this alteration does not change the value of the integral $\int^b_a f(x) dx$.

In lecture we have proven this statement by splitting up the altered $f^*$ into the *old* $f$ function and an indicator function. This approach seems perfectly reasonable for me.

However, I am curious about whether it is possible to show the statement without an indicator function.

Any comments or thoughts on this are welcome.

Comment: Yes. Use the definition of the Riemann integral.

Comment: You only have to prove that it is true for the function that is $0$ everywhere, except at one point.  Then use the fact that if two functions are integrable, their sum is integrable.

Comment: @PeterForeman Is it also possible to show it with the definition of integrability via upper and lower _Darboux_ sums? I am having trouble when it comes to deal with the $\inf$'s and $\sup$'s of the intervals which are induced by the partition. Because I don't know if the single altered point is at all an $\inf$ or $\sup$ in any interval.

Comment: @AlainRemillard, I already mentioned that approach in my OP.

Comment: @Philipp sorry about that. Note to myself, always read the post completely before commenting!

Comment: About Darboux sums, consider ot as two different cases. If the change value is higher, then ifbthe change value is lower.

Comment: @AlainRemillard, then how do I show that it is guarateed that the changed value lies within a interval where it is the supremum/infimum?